# Sylius - product variant creation - Column 'code' cannot be null

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have a problem with generating variants in Sylius.

I know that product variant generator does not generate code automatically so i set it manually, but still getting error during setting variant price on line:

```
$this->channelPricingRepository->add($channelPricing);
```

```
 'INSERT INTO sylius_product_variant (code, created_at, updated_at, position, enabled, product_id, on_hold, on_hand, tracked, width, height, depth, weight, shipping_required, tax_category_id, shipping_category_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "2022-09-22 00:24:06", "2022-09-22 00:24:06", 1, 1, 70, 0, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, 1, null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'code' cannot be null
```

There is my code:

```
            $option = $this->productOptionFactory->createNew();
            $option->setCode(Uuid::uuid4()->toString());
            $option->setName('Test option');

            $valuesData = [
                ['locale' => 'en_US', 'value' => 'test1'],
                ['locale' => 'en_US', 'value' => 'test2'],
                ['locale' => 'en_US', 'value' => 'test3'],
            ];

            foreach ($valuesData as $values) {
                $optionValue = $this->productOptionValueFactory->createNew();

                $optionValue->setCode(Uuid::uuid4()->toString());
                $optionValue->setFallbackLocale($values['locale']);
                $optionValue->setCurrentLocale($values['locale']);
                $optionValue->setValue($values['value']);

                $option->addValue($optionValue);
            }

            $product->addOption($option);

            $this->productVariantGenerator->generate($product);
            foreach($product->getVariants() as $variant){
                $variant->setCode(Uuid::uuid4()->toString());
                $channelPricing = $this->channelPricingFactory->createNew();
                $channelPricing->setPrice(10);
                $channelPricing->setOriginalPrice(10);
                $channelPricing->setChannelCode('FASHION_WEB');
                $channelPricing->setProductVariant($variant);
                $this->channelPricingRepository->add($channelPricing);
                //dd($variant);  
                $variant->addChannelPricing($channelPricing);
            }
            $this->productRepository->add($product);
```

Any ideas why does it happen?

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error message text that the problem is that you're trying to assign a NULL value to the `code` column. As we can't see the content of the values you're assigning to the parameters, it's going to be up to you to figure out why the value is NULL. What does stepping through the code in a debugger tell you is happening?

Comment: Remove this line: $this->channelPricingRepository->add($channelPricing);